# how to clear google search console 404 not found the fast way ?

Tags: seo, google-crawlers

I have 404 not found in my search console about 800k+ link.
But most of the link is just a normal behavior when something is my website is delete it should show 404 not found.

any tips to clear them in the fast way ?

Answer (score 0):

If you've removed a page, you should remove or replace links to that page.

If the same content now exists with a different URL, you should respond with HTTP 301 (Moved Permanently) and also update the links.

Answer (score 0):

Just use google search console option remove URL option, enter url you want to remove, google will remove the particular URL from search.

Comment: The "remove URL" option says it's only good for six months. What if it's a problem with GoogleBot hallucinating a URL that was *never* valid by scraping non-hyperlinked URLs out of commit review UIs and interpreting the trailing `--` from `<!--URL-->` as part of the URL?

Comment: did not work, page do not exist for half year, referer page do not have that 404 link in it. Refferer last crawl in cache do not have this link in it. Yet every week I get new 404 ping for this not existing page. I even get ping for page that has no referer nor sitemap at all.